# How to configure a reverse proxy for multiple IIS sites and a single IP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, binding, reverse-proxy, iisvdir

I've inherited some internal sites from a previous employee and my constraints are the following, it is written in MVC and I need to change how it is hosted and no direct control over DNS. Security won't allow me to use subdomains within DNS so I'd like to use a subdomain within IIS or file path extension. `manage.mgmt.domain.td or mgmt.domain.td/manage as an example`.

How can I configure an IIS binding and an inbound proxy rule so that mgmt.domain.td directs to a general menu page, but `manage1.mgmt.domain.td` directs to a separate page and `manage2.mgmt.domain.td` to another page and have them fully functional. I've been able to configure the inbound reverse proxy rule to use an IP such as `10.0.0.1:801`, however I cannot configure it to working using either friendly format listed above.

Can a vdir, appdir, work with an mvc project or is a reverse proxy better? It's iis10 .

https://computingforgeeks.com/configure-virtual-directory-on-windows-iis-server/

[Edit adding IIS binding and reverse proxy rule image]

[image]

Current

[image: 3/21/22]

Comment: Virtual directory is impossible a destination. Any ASP.NET bits requires an IIS application. And if you don't know what are the differences, read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: Thanks, I found this and converted my vdir to an application. My last hurdle is having dns work. I can type in the ip 10.0.0.1/manage and it points to my site, I can also type 10.0.0.1 and it will load the same content (which I dont' want), however it is not loading content when I use the dns friendly name?

https://docs.xperience.io/k11/installation/deploying-kentico-to-a-live-server/creating-virtual-directories-and-application-pools-in-iis-7-5-and-7-0

Comment: That means you don't understand how site bindings work, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still unsure how to get `mgmt.domain.td` to point to a generic page, but at the same time have bindings set up so `mgmt.domain.td/manage` to point to site 1, `mgmt.domain.td/manageTwo` to point to site 2 and `mgmt.domain.td/manageThree` to point to site 3? How can I get the binding to act as a filter when all 3 sites are bound to 10.0.0.1:80 ? And my internal dns servers point `mgmt.domain.td` to 10.0.0.1 ? How can IIS filter with bindings?

Comment: Learn what is a reverse proxy, as that’s what people use in this situation.

Comment: @LexLi I've got ARR and reverse proxy installed and somewhat working. I notice that when I type `mgmt.domain.td/manage`, it will redirect to `10.0.0.1:801` which is one of the bindings, however I want it to be a subdomain of the dns name mgmt.domain.td `(manage.mgmt.domain.td)` or a file path after domain.td `(mgmt.domain.td/manage)` and I cannot figure out what it wants for a binding, so that I can create an inbound rule that will either redirect/rewrite to that binding. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If I set the inbound rule to "rewrite" it appears to try to point to the correct directory however it prompts for credentials, which fail?

Comment: When the mvc application is a subdomain. It should be add as a site not application under some one site so that you can set its host name to `manage.mgmt.domain.td`. Application and vdir cannot have their own domain under site.

Comment: If different url paths points to different site, you'd better set ARR server as a separate server so that you can understand this solution easily. ARR server binds to domain `mgmt.domain.td`. And other applications deploy on backend server to work as sites. Each application use different ports, for example application1,2,3 are  `10.0.0.1:80, 10.0.1:801,10.0.0.1:802`. Set url rewrite rule on ARR server so that it can reverse proxy `mgmt.domain.td/manage` to `10.0.0.1:80`, `mgmt.domain.td/manageTwo` to `10.0.1:801`, `mgmt.domain.td/manageThree` to `10.0.0.1:802`.

Comment: @BruceZhang when I use a redirect (url rewrite) rule, `mgmt.domain.td/manage` will point to `10.0.0.1:801` and also show that IP and port in the url address bar which I do not want it in the url. When I use a rewrite (url rewrite) rule, I am prompted for credentials and the security logs say I'm generating `a replay attack was detected` issue, so I'm not sure what I don't have configured to make this cohesive.

Comment: Does your organization configure AD for server? If not, please check the Authentication module of IIS if any other authentication enabled and anonymous authentication disabled. Check IIS log to confirm if IIS recevice the same request multiple times in a short period of time. IIS log path:`C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`. If you know failed request tracing, that's a better log trace way.

Comment: @BruceZhang, I'm going to try the virtual app route with filepath `mgmt.domain.td/manage` as I think that's the best option in my environment. I've gotten it to load the page, however no functions work and in the background (under development tools) I see 401's and 500's, as if there is an authentication issue or permissions issue or app pool config issue. Anonymous auth is disabled, and the IIS logs under `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` have the same 401's and 500's. Is this a common issue when you have a parent site and applications under that parent site?

Comment: I figured out the problem, however I don't know how to fix it. With the add application, I apparently have to insert the application alias into the file path. So http://mgmt.domain.td/css/jquery-ui.css fails, however http://mgmt.domain.td/mbrm/css/jquery-ui.css works, with mbrm being the application alias name. Is there a simplistic fix for this?

Comment: `Anonymous auth is disabled` That's the issue, when you use other authentication, you need to provide credentail to verify. Otherwise enable anonymous authentication to disable authentcation. `Is this a common issue when you have a parent site and applications under that parent site?` Yes, applications under parent site will inherit the configuration of the main site including authentication. But it also allow you to configure applications individually to cancel inheritance. You can disable authentication at application level, authentication won't work only when accessing the app's url.

Comment: `Is there a simplistic fix for this?` The role of alias is to distinguish multiple applications under the parent site. If you remove the alias, IIS has no way of knowing which application the client is accessing. This is not recommended if you have to cancel the alias, but it is still possible to rewrite specific requests into the application by configuring url rewrite rule at the parent site level. For example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpbm3.png

Comment: @BruceZhang I implemented the url rewrite rule from your image and I'm getting this error. I assumed that "HTTP_POST" was meant to be a variable, was that correct?

`HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The action's expression "http://{{HTTP_POST}/mbrm{R:0}" is not valid.`

Comment: It is HTTP_HOST, not HTTP_POST :)

Comment: @BruceZhang thanks for that correction. Now I am getting prompted for credentials. Anonymous auth is disabled and in the IIS logs I see 401's and 404's. I was seeing the wrong url redirect in the IIS logs, so I had to make the rewrite url `HTTP://{HTTP_HOST}/mbrm/{R:0}` , does that appear correct? The path is showing up in the logs correctly now, but I am getting prompted for credentials 3 times, which generates a 401 in the logs.

Comment: Here is the log entry from that `2022-03-16 12:02:37 W3SVC14 [server] 10.0.0.1 GET /mbrm/CSS/jquery-ui.theme.css - 80 - 10.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(blah blah %22%7D http://mgmt.domain.td/mbrm mgmt.domain.td 401 2 5 6285 1182 0` and without that slash that I added to the rewrite url, the logs had this `2022-03-16 11:57:23 W3SVC14 [server] 10.0.0.1 GET /mbrmcss/jquery-ui.css - 80 - 10.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0`, specifically the `/mbrmcss/` was problematic and not valid

Comment: Regard to prompted for credentials. You need to check the application on IIS, open authentication module to make sure anonymous authentication is enabled and other are disable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2A1P.png

Comment: {R:0} matched the part of URL that follow the domain name. For example, http://domain/abc/def/ghi, {R;0} is `/abc/def/ghi`. You need to determine whether to add / before {R:0} according to the url in the application

Comment: @BruceZhang I have tried `domain.com/{R:0}, domain.com{R:0}, domain.com/mbr/{R:0} and domain.com/mbr[R:0}` and all of them have 404's as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/66mkI.jpg so to me it appears the urlrewrite rule is not doing anything or else the page would render correctly with the `/mbr/` portion somewhere within it, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET applications run in application pool. When you add vdir, you cannot choose application pool. So add application is more suitable than vdir.
[image]

> I can type in the ip 10.0.0.1/manage and it points to my site, I can also type 10.0.0.1 and it will load the same content (which I dont' want)

`10.0.0.1/manage` is the correct url to access MVC application. If `10.0.0.1` also show same content, consider that client cache or url redirect. The correct content it shows should be index page of the main site.
[image]

> however it is not loading content when I use the dns friendly name?

I cannot understand what the dns friendly name you mean. If you have a public domain name, just bind the domain to the server in server provider. and when you add site, set the host name to it.
[image]

Comment: When referring to DNS, I need a way to be able to redirect which site using a unique identifier of a subdomain or of a filepath after the top domain? I want to be able to do this internally on the IIS server so that I am not beholden to another group of people (the DNS team). Can site bindings be used in this way?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is to add a route to your application, for example on global.asax, to get the incoming server address from there and direct it to the correct destination. For Application_Begin_Request in Mvc, you can refer to this article [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/18/How-do-ASPNET-Application-Events-Work).